# Django server runs twice for the same process

Tags: python, django

when I execute the run server command or reload the server it runs the stat loader twice for the same process.

[image: Output]

I used `os.getpid()` to affirm that I'm running two processes but why did the single execution cause the process to run twice?

[image: process Ids]

the latest updates was adding django_cleanup package

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
# Default django apps:
'ckeditor',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'djmoney',
'modeltranslation',
'django.contrib.admin',

# Installed apps
'server.pxora',

# Third party
'rest_framework',
'corsheaders',
'storages',
'fcm_django',
'django_celery_beat',
'phonenumber_field',
'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig',
```

]

Comment: can you share a bit of detail about any settings changes you have made before? I am curious to understand why such a case may arise.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any configuration codes it's impossible to determine the problem,

but I would suggest trying running without reload maybe it would help to debug the problem.You can turn off the auto-reload process.

When running try this --noreload option like that:

```
python manage.py runserver --noreload
```

Comment: I am actively working on Django these days. I would like to know what may cause the double reloading, can you give some insight on that? Why an option like --noreload was given while executing the runserver, shouldn't it be mandatory for single-time reload?

Comment: As I mentioned before, it would be more easier to figure out your issue, if you added your main files. Definitely you have some code causing the problem

Comment: I add the installed apps @Mathpdegeek497